# If $\phi$ is entire and satisfies $|\phi(z)| \leq e^{|z|}$, then $|\phi'(z)| \leq c e^{|z|}$ for some $c > 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $\phi$ is entire and satisfies $|\phi(z)| \leq e^{|z|}$, then $|\phi'(z)| \leq c e^{|z|}$ for some $c > 0$.

I saw this problem on a practice qual but I had no idea what to do.  It looks similar to having $|\phi(z)| \leq |e^z|$ (the answer would be obvious if this were the case).  Would someone give me a hint?

Comment: Does Cauchy's integral formula help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Cauchy's formula:
$$\phi'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}\,dz$$
and by taking absolute values:
$$\left|\phi'(z_0)\right|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{2\pi r}{r^2}\cdot\max_{|z-z_0|=r}\left|\phi(z)\right|\leq \frac{e^{r}}{r}\cdot e^{|z_0|}. $$
We are still free to choice an optimal radius $r$: by choosing $r=1$,
$$ \left|\phi'(z_0)\right| \leq e\cdot e^{|z_0|}$$
follows.